# How to safely give non-root access to lib so that Catalyst hardware acceleration can function?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, ati

I've installed AMD Catalyst 13.8 BETA2 by following [these directions](https://askubuntu.com/a/379286/128334).

It works fine on the administrative user it was setup with, but a non-admin user gets the black screen on login.

Non-admin user works in software rendering mode but not hardware.

**`cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log`**

```
[ 42815.421] (EE) AIGLX error: failed to open /usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so, error[/usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
[ 42815.421] (EE) AIGLX error: failed to open /usr/lib64/dri/fglrx_dri.so, error[/usr/lib64/dri/fglrx_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
[ 42815.421] (EE) AIGLX error: failed to open /usr/X11R6/lib/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so, error[/usr/X11R6/lib/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
```

From the installation, there was this command:

```
sudo ln -s lib /usr/lib64
```

`ls -l /lib` shows that root user and root group own the directory and subdirectories.

How can non-admin users safely get the necessary access to these files?

---

**Note:** the symlink command has been corrected in the linked instructions.

Comment: are you sure those files exist?

Comment: @Braiam Thank you for looking!  I just `sudo dir`ed them, and the directories do not exist.  The admin user doesn't give this error in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` when logging in.  The files do exist in `/usr/lib/dri/`, `/usr/lib/fglrx/dri/`, and `/usr/lib32/fglrx/dri/`.

Comment: Where did you run the `ln` command from?

Comment: @terdon Thank-you for looking!  The admin user.  I tried doing the same command for the non-admin user, but it won't work since non-admin user is not in sudo list.  Sorry, I'm still extremely noob.

Comment: I asked where you ran the command _from_, the instructions you link to say `cd /usr ; sudo ln -svT lib /usr/lib64` is that what you ran? Were you in the `/usr` directory when you ran `ln`?

Comment: @terdon Ah, lol, I have to plead noobity again.  I think I ran it from my admin user's `~` directory.  Can't be sure, but it seems like it worked for the admin user because it doesn't give those errors in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.  Does that help?  Many thanks again!

Comment: @terdon Argh, I think I see what you mean now.  The directions in the specific linked answer didn't `cd` into `/usr` or `ln -sVT`.  Would you mind showing me how to find and undo the previous link?  Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @Gracchus I've edited your link, it should point to the right one now.

Comment: @terdon No, I followed the 13.10 instructions.  Makes sense since it worked when I was on 13.04  The poster accidentally posted the incorrect command for the symlink.  Can you show me how to undo that symbolic link?  Again thank you so much in advance!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11883/discussion-between-terdon-and-gracchus)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I'm starting to get what happened. One of the answers on the page you linked to tells you to run this:

```
cd /usr ; sudo ln -svT lib /usr/lib64
```

That will i) move you into the `/usr` directory and ii) create a link called `lib64` (which will be `/usr/lib64` if you run the `ln` command in `/usr`) pointing to `/usr/lib`. The command should not be run as your admin user (that's why it has `sudo`) and it should certainly not be run from your admin user's `$HOME` directory.

Please re-read the instructions and follow them *exactly*. Also read this note (included just under the `ln` command):

> (Note: The second command shouldn't be necessary if there is already such a symbolic link named lib64 pointing to folder lib there. And if there is already a real folder by that name (determined with ls -l /usr/lib64), you should ensure that its contents are safely moved into folder /usr/lib and then delete --the now empty-- folder /usr/lib64 before executing this command).

So, make sure there is no `/usr/lib64` directory, if there is, move its contents to `/lib` before running the `ln` command.

---

NOTE: The actual `ln` command in my answer is `ln -svT lib /usr/lib64`, if that is really what you ran, the link will be created at `/usr/lib64` irrespective of where you run it from.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but would you mind changing your answer to show how I followed the incorrect symlink in my question?  I'll edit the question to show that the linked answer has since been edited with the right command.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @Gracchus sure, that was the answer I got when I clicked on your link which is why I phrased it that way. The stackexchange pages change the order of the answers randomly, only the accepted stays on top.

Comment: Ack!  Sorry about that.  Again, thank you so much!

Comment: @Gracchus actually, I'm probably wrong here. If you ran `ln -s lib /usr/lib64` you should have created the link in the right place because you gave an absolute path.

Comment: It looks like you were initially correct since after using the proper command, the non-admin user can now login with hardware acceleration.  Either way, thank you very much for figuring this out for me!  (Ah, and in my noobish opinion, the original command probably didn't work because there's no `lib` in my `~` or its subdirectories...?)